# Use of Mysql index

Tags: mysql

1. MYISAM table type or engine - creates 3 files on disk for each table.

   1. for structure .frm
   2. for data .myd
   3. for index .myi
      If I create new index for already existed table, which files from above get changed?
2. When we create index, what exactly happends to the data in table?
   does the records in table get chenged for indexed column?
3. If we insert new record as `name = aaass`, `salary = 40500`, at which position the record is stored? at the end? or as we created index, it will store bellow the name= aaab?

e.g table is

```
id name salary
1  aaa   20000
2  ddd   23000
3  aaabb 10000
4  dddqa 40000
```

if I create index on name, then does data gets rearraged as follows?

```
id name salary
1  aaa   20000
3  aaabb 10000
2  ddd   23000
4  dddqa 40000
```

If not then what is the use of index?

Comment: Data doesn't get rearranged, unless you use InnoDB and modify the primary key manually but that's another topic. Index is used so that data file doesn't have to be scanned sequentially. That means that index file is stored in certain order/structure and in theory, data file shouldn't be touched if you add indexes (to existing columns). I'm not MyISAM expert but the data is probably appended to the end of file, as it's the fastest way to write something to the disk.

Comment: This is interview material? Or homework?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new index for already existed table then `.frm` and `.myi` files should get updated as `.frm` will get updated with new index in table definition and `myi` file will get updated with new index tree.

`PRIMARY KEY` defined on a table is a `clustured index` in which records are stored in sorted order based on key order.